# Use conda env for ExternalLanguage cell?

Tags: stylesheet, external-calls, python, version-11.3

I really like the new 'ExternalLanguage' cell in v11.3. Is there a way to tell the cell to use a specific conda environment, either as default or for a specific input cell?

[image]

Mathematica can find anaconda:

[image]

But doesn't list any of my envs

[image]

Trying to register them fails without a message:

[image]

**Updates:**

I can't start an external session:

[image]

The syntax highlighting seems to be off, how do I turn it on?

[image]

Comment: The first part is answered by https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167605/38205. The second part (syntax highlighting) isn't implemented for python.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What about not being able to run StartExternalSession for any conda environment, has anyone complained about that yet?

Comment: ZMQ isn't installed for Conda. See this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155815/38205 for how to get venv (or other types of distros) working.

Comment: Ah-ha, all I had to do was pip install zmq and now my conda env shows up in FindExternalEvaluators!

Comment: The syntax highlight is not *off*, it is simply not implemented for python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [SetLanguageCellSession](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/SetLanguageCellSession). I've just answered a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219032/how-to-set-default-version-for-an-external-language-code-cell), see that answer for an explanation of how what you want can be done in version 12.1+:

[image]