# Create "Python Code" cells using custom executable

Tags: cells, python, external-calls

In https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155815/45020 it is explained how to run cells using a custom virtual environment. How can I quickly create a cell that is evaluated using this environment. Normally I can hit > at the beginning of a cell to create a "Python Code" cell. However, this will use the default Python environment. Is there any way to quickly create a cell that uses a custom executable that I set up using RegisterExternalEvaluator?

Comment: I use [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/mikesollami/DeployedResources/Function/SetLanguageCellSession)

Comment: Thanks, I found that after posting in an answer to a similar question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236298/45020. (My question should probably be considered a duplicate of that one.) However, this function does not work for me. I left a comment about it below the linked answer. I run an exact example from the documentation and run into errors.

Comment: It is currently working for you? Then it might be a version issue. I am using "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)".

Comment: I don't have version 12.1 to test on right now, but it works in 12.2 for mac:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fckeP.png